# XPages: Customizing lotusDialogBox

Tags: lotus-notes

How could i Enhance Lotus Notes Dialog Boxes or Picklists to  change the Background Colorsof one dialogBox on a page with out affecting the others?

Comment: Three is nothing in xpages called Dialog Boxes, Picklist or Lotus Notes, please edit your question so we understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Lotus Notes dialogs and picklist there is nothing you can do - it is Windows application, so dialog windows inherit look&feel from operating system.
You can alter look of content in dialog boxes by [making your own layouts](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DESIGNING_A_FORM_THAT_PRESENTS_A_DIALOG_BOX.html), though.

I have removed `xpages` and `css` tatgs - as mentioned in comment, it has nothing to do with XPages design. If that was your case, simply define CSS class and your own CSS. Look at DOM hierarchy with Firebug or developer tools of modern browsers.